# How to access wd specific mobile apis using protractor

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, appium

I have used below mentioned hook to use the wd specific apis but I am not able to do it. Suppose I want to close the app. How can I go for it. Also it is reading the wdBrowser but it not printing the context when calling currentContext()

```
'use strict';
var log4js = require('log4js');
var fs = require('fs');

exports.config = {

    capabilities: {
        browserName: '',
        platformName: 'Android',
        platformVersion: '6.0',
        deviceName: 'ZX1D62CVWH',
        autoWebview: true,

        // change this path to the absolute path of the app
        app: '/Users/abhishek/abhishek-test-volunteeringMobileApp/android-debug.apk'
    },


    //restartBrowserBetweenTests: true,
    // Framework to use. Jasmine is recommended.
    framework: 'jasmine2',

    // Spec patterns are relative to the current working directory when
    // protractor is called.


    specs: ['Specs/LoginSpec.js'],

    seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4723/wd/hub',
    //  'seleniumAddress': 'http://hub-cloud.browserstack.com/wd/hub',

    // Override the timeout for webdriver to 20 seconds.
    allScriptsTimeout: 90000,
    getPageTimeout: 90000,


    // Options to be passed to Jasmine.
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 90000,
        showColors: true
            // allScriptsTimeout: 50000
    },




    onPrepare: function() {

        // implicit and page load timeouts
        browser.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(40000);
        browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(25000);

        // for non-angular page
        // browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');
        jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
            new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
                captureOnlyFailedSpecs: true,
                savePath: './Web_Automation_Summary',
                takeScreenShotsOnlyForFailedSpecs: true,
                cleanDestination: true,
                fileName: 'Automation_Report'
            })
        );

        var wd = require('wd'),
            protractor = require('protractor'),
            wdBridge = require('wd-bridge')(protractor, wd);
        wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);
    }

}
```

Spec.js

```
describe('Login page testcases', function() {


    it('should print context of the device', function() {

         wdBrowser.currentContext().then(function(value) {
            console.log(+value)
        })
         browser.quit();
    });
```

Comment: Can you paste your spec-file here?

Comment: @wswebcreation Updated

Comment: All code looks good, but:
1. is the app really open when you log the context? 2. What happens if you remove the `browser.quit();`. As far as I know you never need to do a `browser.quit();` because protractor will do that when all stepfiles are run.

Comment: 1) Yes, it opens up. 2) Even if I remove it it mainly remains same

Comment: Hmm, then there's something else bugging this. Can't see it with this code. Do you have an example project?

Answer (score 0):

More info about the WD-API can be found [here](https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md). You just need to use the global `wdBrowser`-object in stead of the global protractor `browser`-object to access the API.

Also check if you need to change your context (NATIVE / WEBVIEW) before executing a method on the app.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem I am facing is that the global object wdBrowser is not able to invoke its methods. like  wdBrowser.currentContext().then(function(value) {
            console.log(value)
        })....... This doesn't print the context value

Comment: capabilities: {
        browserName: '',
        platformName: 'Android',
        platformVersion: '6.0',
        deviceName: 'ZX1D62CVWH',
        autoWebview: true,

        // change this path to the absolute path of the app
        app: '/Users/abhishek/abhishek-test-volunteeringMobileApp/android-debug.apk'
    },

Comment: Did you place the code with `wdBridge.initFromProtractor(exports.config);` in the onPrepare? If so, can you paste the config and your spec file here?

Comment: please check the updated question. I mentioned my onPrepare code

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of things I can see:

- Putting `browser.quit()` where you have it will quit before the currentContext promise has resolved - it's not needed anyway.
- `console.log(+value)` is syntactically incorrect: should be `console.log(value)`
- You can use `done` in the function signature to make protractor wait until that function is called

So try something like this:

```
describe('Login page testcases', function() {
    it('should print context of the device', function(done) {
         wdBrowser.currentContext().then(function(value) {
            console.log(value);
            done();        
        });
    });
});
```